# Defining a generic to be a case class

Tags: scala

In this example, I want the generic `T` to be a `case class` and a `DAOEntity` with `id`, so in the abstract implementation, I can use the `copy` method.

How to define it?

```scala
trait DAOEntity {
  def id: String
}

// How to define this generic to force the use of a `case class` to have access to `copy`?
abstract class DAO[T <: DAOEntity] {
  def storeInUppercase(entity: T): T = entity.copy(id = entity.id)
}

case class MyEntity(id: String) extends DAOEntity

class MyEntityDAO extends DAO[MyEntity] {
  // Other stuff
}
```

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Could you add it as a response? I will happy to mark it as the right one and maybe I will create a ticker in Scala asking for a new feature. I know that case classes are implementing Product trait. Maybe is possible to do something like this in future versions. I know that will be not easy because, for example, copy signature is created on compileation tim. But maybe people has other ideas.

Comment: What would the signature of a generic `copy` method look like?

Comment: @LeviRamsey You are right. That is what I mean when I said "I know that will be not easy because, for example, copy signature is created on compilation time. But maybe people have other ideas." No idea how to resolve that problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to know if a type is a `case class` or not.
And even if there was, you won't get the `copy` method. The language doesn't provide a way to abstract over constructor; thus neither `copy` and factories *(`apply` on companions)* by extension. Which makes sense, what would be the type signature of such function?

What you can do instead is create a factory-like **typeclass** and ask for that:

```scala
trait DAOFactory[T <: DAOEntity] {
  def copy(oldEntity: T, newId: String): T
}
object DAOFactory {
  def instance[T <: DAOEntity](f: (T, String) => T): DAOFactory[T] =
    new DAOFactory[T] {
      override final def copy(oldEntity: T, newId: String): T =
        f(oldEntity, newId)
    }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```scala
abstract class DAO[T <: DAOEntity](implicit factory: DAOFactory[T]) {
  def storeInUppercase(entity: T): T =
    factory.copy(
      oldEntity = entity,
      newId = entity.id.toUpperCase
    )
}
```

And entities would provide the instance like this:

```scala
final case class MyEntity(id: String, age: Int) extends DAOEntity
object MyEntity {
  implicit final val MyEntityFactory: DAOFactory[MyEntity] =
    DAOFactory.instance {
      case (oldEntity, newId) =>
        oldEntity.copy(id = newId)
    }
}

// This compile thanks to the instance in the companion object.
object MyEntityDAO extends DAO[MyEntity]
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/zUV3Lin1TuesJmnKz7fNww/2)*.